# How to avoid httpsURLConnection.getInputStream() in Android hanging if incorrect login credentials are provided?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

Authentication credentials are set here, everything works perfectly if user/password provided is correct, but it hangs if they are incorrect. It's not the server issues, I checked with Curl and Browser, incorrect credentials return 401 right away.:

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
        }
    });
```

Code that hangs is here,it hangs on this line: in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConn.getInputStream())); (No exception, it just stays on this line)

```
    try {
        URL url = new URL(resourceUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        String rawData = "";
        String currentLine = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConn.getInputStream()));
        while ((currentLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            rawData = rawData.concat(currentLine);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.i(CLASS_NAME + "::" + METHOD_NAME
                , "An exception occured while reading data from remote host. httpURLConn.responseCode = " + httpURLConn.getResponseCode()
                + " / httpURLConn.responseMessage = " + httpURLConn.getResponseMessage(), e);
        throw new UnknownHostException();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(CLASS_NAME + "::" + METHOD_NAME
                , "An exception occured while reading data from remote host. httpURLConn.responseCode = " + httpURLConn.getResponseCode()
                + " / httpURLConn.responseMessage = " + httpURLConn.getResponseMessage(), e);
        throw new IOException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the server is keeping the connection alive (Keep-Alive header)?

Comment: Nope, no Keep-Alive header in the response